# Hibernate: more than one eager collections-properties that belongs to the same hierarchy tree

Tags: hibernate, jpa

As we all know, hibernate *doesn't allow to use more than one eager-collections* in one entity for the atomicity reasons. It happens, because it can't pull two different collection from different tables in one query.

**Question:** *But what about the situation when two eager-collections belong two the same hierarchy tree? Is there any way to achieve two eager-collections in the same entity-object?*

**How I imagine this:** If we use for example table-per-class inheritance strategy and two collections belongs to this hierarchy, than they can be pulled in one request (thanks for union-operation).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your problem is, but if you use JPQL or Criteria API and define those relations to be fetched - they will be fetched in an atomic operation on most databases. Just make sure to check that size of resultset wont affect the performance.

Comment: I'm using Postgre. And when I try to declare more than one eagerly-fetched collection - the MultipleBagError.

Comment: As you said, the new Hibernate version seems to have a feature with OneToMany relations when they are fetched eager.

OneToOne, ManyToOne and ManyToMany relations still work fine with eager fetch type. Every single OneToMany relation, which is declared with fetch type eager crashes the deployment of my application. (c)
[https://community.jboss.org/thread/107685?tstart=0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch multiple collections but to avoid the `MultipleBagError` avoid using `List`.

If you have no more than 1 List and the rest of your collections are `Set`s then it should work. Just make sure the classes used in those sets have good equals() and hashCode() methods.

*Update to answer your question in the comments:*
Lists allow duplicate entries, Sets don't (as long as equals/hashCode are implemented properly).

A database query that joins multiple tables produces a cartesian product (multiple rows that actually represent your single entity). If there's only one collection then Hibernate can assume the multiple rows all belong to that collection. If there are multiple collections though, you need to manage that yourself by using a Set to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't grasp it: why it is allowed for Set, and isn't for List?